# MySQL: Is it possible to have slave in-memory database?

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave, in-memory-database

Is it possible to configure slave in-memory database?

Master db is common, slave for read only operation could suit well into [in-memory storage](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/memory-storage-engine.html).

If it is not possible with MySQL, what are other database to use such scheme?

Comment: Have you found any better answer on this? I would like to do the same.

Comment: Not found. Start a bounty if you want to draw attention and know what could be used.

Answer (score 1):

It might work for 'simple' slave, such as data size and replication, as well as tolerate lots of limits with the in-memory storage engine.

Comment: Could you please extend answer, and add some links?

Comment: It has been done using libslave to write to Tarantool, described here: [link](http://highscalability.com/blog/2017/3/29/how-to-speed-up-your-mysql-with-replication-to-in-memory-dat.html). Disclosure: I have been involved for money with both MySQL and Tarantool.